# Import issues with jQuery.UI.Combined ASP.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to use the `dialog` UI feature in jQuery in an ASP.net application. By default, ASP.net has the jQuery library, but not the UI library. I used NuGet to download jQuery.UI.Combined version 1.12.1 and switched the version of jQuery to 1.12.1 to match. Currently I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function` when trying to use the dialog feature. Here is my code:

```
<head>
    <link href="~/Content/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

...


    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
        <select>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="target" value="click" />
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#dialog").hide();
    $("#target").click(function () {
        $("#dialog").show();
        $("#dialog").dialog();
    });
</script>
```

Am I getting this error becuase of import errors or is the code just wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: N.B. you don't need your jQuery version to match exactly. Per the [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/1.12/) jQuery UI 1.12 supports jQuery 1.7 and newer.

Comment: Anyway in regards to your error...are you sure the file loaded itself into your page correctly? Check your network tools as the page first loads and ensure you've specified the path correctly, not getting a 404 or something. I can't see why else it would fail. Can you use any other jQueryUI functions?

Comment: @ADyson I just checked, no 404 error. The only error I get is when I hit that input I get the `TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function` error

Comment: Are you absolutely certain? You checked in the Network tools, not the Console, right? (And with the tools opened _before_ you start to load the page? And network monitoring switched on, if your browser requires it?). Because if jQueryUI is loaded correctly, your code should work. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ykq5hcLv/1/

Comment: @ADyson just checked again, the network tool in Chrome doesn'tshow any errors, the only error that show up was the dailog error, and a warning about deprecation of `Element.createShadowRoot`

Comment: And the jQuery UI JS file is shown in the Network list, with a status of 200 ok? Is that correct?

Comment: @ADyson yes, that is correct

Comment: I'm a bit stumped then, sorry. It looks like it should work. Only one other thing I can think...your script block at the bottom is outside the body tag. I've never tested that but I'm pretty sure it shouldn't be. It might be making it execute before anything else is loaded, including the scripts in the head. Although I'm not sure because I'd have thought it would generate an error about not finding the main jQuery either. But can you humour me and move it inside the bottom of the body tag and see if it makes any difference?

Comment: @ADyson just moved the script inside the body tag but I got the same error

Comment: @ADyson I did notice that it's checking `jquery-1.12.1.min.js` for the dialog widget instead of  `jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js`, could that be the problem?

Comment: not sure what you mean? Are you saying the stack trace indicates an error in jQuery.min.js rather than jqueryui.min.js? Can you post the full stack trace?